# All possible combinations of list elements in Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list `B` containing elements. I want to create all possible pairs using these elements as shown in the expected output. But I am getting an error. How do I fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

B=[ 1,  2,  5,  7, 10, 11]
combination=[]  

for L in range(len(B) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(B, L):
        combination.append([list(sub) for sub in subset])
combination
```

The error is

```
in <listcomp>
    combination.append([list(sub) for sub in subset])

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The expected output is

```
[1,2],[1,5],[1,7],[1,10],[1,11],
[2,1],[2,5],[2,7],[2,10],[2,11],
[5,1],[5,2],[5,7],[5,10],[5,11],
[7,1],[7,2],[7,5],[7,10],[7,11],
[10,1],[10,2],[10,5],[10,7],[10,11],
[11,1],[11,2],[11,5],[11,7],[11,10]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is not `combinations` but `permutations`:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations(B, 2))
[(1, 2),
 (1, 5),
 (1, 7),
 (1, 10),
 (1, 11),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 7),
 (2, 10),
 (2, 11),
 (5, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 7),
 (5, 10),
 (5, 11),
 (7, 1),
 (7, 2),
 (7, 5),
 (7, 10),
 (7, 11),
 (10, 1),
 (10, 2),
 (10, 5),
 (10, 7),
 (10, 11),
 (11, 1),
 (11, 2),
 (11, 5),
 (11, 7),
 (11, 10)]
```

To convert to a list:

```
# List comprehension
perm = [list(p) for p in itertools.permutations(B, 2)

# Functional programming
perm = list(map(list, itertools.permutations(B, 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I convert each element to list? For example, ```(1,2)``` should be ```[1,2]```.

Comment: `list(map(list, itertools.permutations(B, 2)))`

Answer (score 0):

Beside the @Corralien answer which is the correct one, i am just correcting your solution to let you know that your solution can also be made to work just changing few things

1. Do not convert & iterate subset as it is already a list and its element is not iterable
2. Replace combinations with permutations
3. Add a condition to filter only two combinations as your code is producing permutation of N X N

Final version is following.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

B=[ 1,  2,  5,  7, 10, 11]
combination=[]  

for L in range(len(B) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(B, L):
        if len(subset) == 2:
            combination.append(subset)
print(combination)
```

OUTPUT

> ## [(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 10), (1, 11), (2, 1), (2, 5), (2, 7), (2, 10), (2, 11), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 7), (5, 10), (5, 11), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 5), (7, 10), (7, 11), (10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 5), (10, 7), (10, 11), (11, 1), (11, 2), (11, 5), (11, 7), (11, 10)]